# Generating random results without repetition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying different ways to randomize the questions in a little quiz I'm making, but all the methods I'm finding are using a function that will still repeat items when you end the function and call it again. I've tried using pop to do it but have only run into that same issue.

Here is some of my code for reference.

```
    import time
    import math
    qlist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    tlist=['true','True','T','t']
    flist=['False','false','F','f']
    ylist=['Yes','yes','Yep','yep','y','Y']
    nlist=['No','no','nah','Nah','N','n']
    alist=['a','A','a)','A)']
    blist=['b','B','b)','B)']
    clist=['c','C','c)','c)']
    dlist=['d','D','d)','D)']
    
    def main():
        print("__________________________________")
        print("|Welcome to the random facts test|")
        print("----------------------------------")
        time.sleep(1.5)
    
        print('________________________________________')
        print('|This is a replacement question because of the language used|')
        print("----------------------------------------")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        q1 = input('--->  ')
        if q1 in tlist:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('Correct! 1/10')
        else:
             print('Incorrect. Would you like to play again?')
             yn2 = input('--->  ')
             if yn2 in nlist:
                 quit()
             if yn2 in ylist:
                 main()
    
        print('___________________')
        print('|Octopuses have...|')
        print("-------------------")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('a) Three hearts')
        print('b) One heart')
        print('c) Five hearts')
        print('d) Two hearts')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        q2 = input('--->  ')
        if q2 in alist:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('Correct! 2/10')
        else:
             print('Incorrect. Would you like to play again?')
             yn2 = input('--->  ')
             if yn2 in nlist:
                 quit()
             if yn2 in ylist:
                 main()
    
        print('__________________')
        print('|Tomataoes are...|')
        print('------------------')
        print('a) Fruit')
        print('b) Vegitables')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        q3 = input('--->  ')
        if q3 in alist:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('Correct! 3/10')
        else:
             print('Incorrect. Would you like to play again?')
             yn2 = input('--->  ')
             if yn2 in nlist:
                 quit()
             if yn2 in ylist:
                 main()
    
        print('_____________________________________________________')
        print('|This is a replacement question because of the language used|')
        print('-----------------------------------------------------')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('a) one')
        print('b) seven')
        print('c) two')
        print('d) three')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        q4 = input('--->  ')
        if q4 in clist:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('Correct! 4/10')
        else:
             print('Incorrect. Would you like to play again?')
             yn2 = input('--->  ')
             if yn2 in nlist:
                 quit()
             if yn2 in ylist:
                 main()
    
        print('______________________________________________')
        print("|True or false, Mars' atmosphere is 10KM high|")
        print('----------------------------------------------')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        q5 = input('--->  ')
        if q5 in tlist:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('Correct! 5/10')
        else:
             print('Incorrect. Would you like to play again?')
             yn2 = input('--->  ')
             if yn2 in nlist:
                 quit()
             if yn2 in ylist:
                 main()
    
        print('_______________________________________')
        print('|The old english word for orange is...|')
        print('---------------------------------------')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('a) Grognar')
        print('b) Crog')
        print('c) Clept')
        print('d) Tangerine')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        q6 = input('--->  ')
        if q6 in blist:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('Correct! 6/10')
        else:
             print('Incorrect. Would you like to play again?')
             yn2 = input('--->  ')
             if yn2 in nlist:
                 quit()
             if yn2 in ylist:
                 main()
    
    
        print('______________________________________________________________________')
        print('|Both The church of satan and the satanic temple have this in common.|')
        print('----------------------------------------------------------------------')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('a) They believe in satan')
        print("b) They don't believe in satan")
        print('c) they have some sort of sacred text')
        print("d) They don't have any sort of sacred texts")
        q7 = input('--->  ')
        if q7 in blist:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('Correct! 7/10')
        else:
             print('Incorrect. Would you like to play again?')
             yn2 = input('--->  ')
             if yn2 in nlist:
                 quit()
             if yn2 in ylist:
                 main()
        
        print('_______________________________________')
        print('|What Does Hexennacht mean in english?|')
        print('---------------------------------------')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("a) Witches' Night")
        print("b) Night of the Undead")
        print('c) Nothing. It doesnt mean anything.')
        print("d) None of the above.")
        q8 = input('--->  ')
        if q8 in alist:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('Correct! 8/10')
        else:
             print('Incorrect. Would you like to play again?')
             yn2 = input('--->  ')
             if yn2 in nlist:
                 quit()
             if yn2 in ylist:
                 main()
    
    
    
    
    main()
```

Comment: I would suggest making the questions, answers, and options all values of a dictionary with a different key for each set of data. Then use a function to randomize the order of the keys, then parse the question/answer format. The order should not repeat since your function should be created in a way that returns a new instance of your quiz each time.

Comment: I'd suggest also writing a single "question" function which takes a prompt as an argument and prints the question formatted the way you like, and also takes the answer list. Perhaps just make it a method of a `Quiz` class like @boostedd suggests.

Comment: better use `random.shuffle(list)` to get random order on the list - and then you can use `for item on list:...` to get items without repetition

Comment: running `main()` inside `main()` is called `recursion` and you could write code without `recurison`.

Comment: if you have code with `pop` and it doesn't work then show it in question and we may try to fix it. Now you shows code which works so there is nothing to fix it - and we will not write all code from scratch to modify it.

Comment: you should keep `question` with `answers` and correct answer as single object - ie. `dictionary` and then you can simply shuffle it to get random it in random order. If you keep it in separated elements then it hard to shuffle it and keep `question` with matching anawers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show how you try to get random elements so you could do something what changes order back to original.

You can use `random.shuffle(list)` to set random order on the list.
And then you can use `for item on list: ...` to get items without repetition.

```
import random

all_questions = [
    'Octopuses have...',
    'Tomataoes are...',
    "True or false, Mars' atmosphere is 10KM high",
]

questions_order = list(range(len(all_questions)))

random.shuffle(questions_order)

for number in questions_order:
    print(all_questions[number])
    # ... allowed answers ...
    # ... get user anser ...
    # ... check user answer ...
    # ... change result ...
```

if you would keep question, answers and correct_answer on one list then you could do it simpler

```
import random

all_questions = [
    {'question': 'Octopuses have...', 
      'answers': ['a...', 'b...', 'c...', 'd...'], 
      'correct': 'a'},

    {'question': 'Tomataoes are...', 
      'answers': ['a...', 'b...', 'c...', 'd...'], 
      'correct': 'a'},
    {'question': "True or false, Mars' atmosphere is 10KM high", 
      'answers': [], 
      'correct': 'Y'},
]

random.shuffle(all_questions)

for question in all_questions:
    print('question:', question['question'])
    print('answers:',  question['answers'])
    print('correct:',  question['correct'])
    print('--------------------')
```

---

Minimal working code with other ideas

```
import random

all_questions = [
    {
        'question': 'Octopuses have...',
        'answers': [
            'a) Three hearts',
            'b) One heart',
            'c) Five hearts',
            'd) Two hearts',
        ],
        'allowed': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
        'correct': 'a',
    },
    {
        'question': 'Tomataoes are...',
        'answers': [
            'a) Fruit',
            'b) Vegitables',
        ],
        'allowed': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
        'correct': 'a',
    },
    {
        'question': "True or false, Mars' atmosphere is 10KM high",
        'answers': [],
        'allowed': ('y', 'n'),
        'correct': 'y',
    },
]

def game():
    # --- before for-loop ---

    random.shuffle(all_questions)

    result = 0
    questions_number = len(all_questions)

    # --- for-loop ---

    for question in all_questions:

        # display question
        lenght = len(question['question'])
        print(f"+-{'-'*lenght}-+")
        print(f"| {question['question']} |")
        print(f"+-{'-'*lenght}-+")
        
        # display answers
        for item in question['answers']:
            print(item)
        
        # wait for allowed answer
        allowed_txt = ', '.join(question['allowed'])

        while True:
            answer = input(f"Select {allowed_txt} >>>  ")
            # convert to lower
            answer = answer.lower()

            # check only if answer is allowed
            if answer in question['allowed']:
                break  # exit `while True`
            else:
                print("I don't understand your answer. Try Again.")
                
        # check if answer is correct
        if answer == question['correct']:
            result += 1
            print(f'Correct! {result}/{questions_number}')            
        else:
            print(f'Wrong! {result}/{questions_number}')

        print('-=*=-'*5)

    # --- after for-loop ---

    percent = int( (result/questions_number)*100 )

    print(f'Your final result: {result}/{questions_number} ({percent}%)')
    #print(f'Your final result: {result}/{questions_number} ({result/questions_number:.0%})')
    
# --- main ---

while True:
    game()

    while True:
        answer = input("Again [y or n]? ")
        answer = answer.lower()
                
        # check only if answer is allowed - `y or n`                
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break  # exit `while True`
        else:
            print("I don't understand your answer")

    # now I check if I have to repeate game or exit
    if answer == 'n':
        break  # exit `while True`
```

I check only single char answers `a`, `y`, `n` because I don't like to write long answers.

I don't allow to restart or quit game between questions.